# How to center a label located inside a wrapped div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a long div containing columnar data:

```
A very
Big chicken
Comes to
Dine with us
Every day
```

I used the following style

```
<div style="flex: 1; width: 180px; height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column;">
        <div>A very</div>
        <div>Big chicken</div>
        <div>Comes to</div>
        <div>Dine with us</div>
        <div>Every day</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To make it wrap the data so that I have many columns

```
A very         Dine with us
Big chicken    Every day
Comes to
```

I am trying to add a label below the whole thing, but since I set the div width to a certain value, centering it will display it shifted to the left because it doesn't consider the size of the whole div due to wrapping.

```
A very         Dine with us
Big chicken    Every day
Comes to   

   LABEL
```

How can I achieve what I want, which is:

```
A very         Dine with us
Big chicken    Every day
Comes to   

            LABEL
```

Comment: If you have a known height and a known font-size/line-height, you may use order and transform, but this is tricky. best would be to use display:grid or take your label outside the column container. Your bit of code doesn't show your trouble. Can you clarify your question so an efficient answer / advise could be proposed

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is a table. Then a div holding the label and some CSS so you can control its positioning. Here is a working example on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPmOWR

```
<div style="flex: 1; width: 280px; height: 100%;">
 <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>A Very</th>
      <th>Dine With us</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Big Chicken</td>
      <td>Every Day</td> 
    </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Comes to</td>  
</tr>
</table>
    <div class="label"> LABEL</div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.label{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
     background: red;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the label text to be relatively centered you will need it to be inside a container which has the same width as the container that has your data in it.

I modified your code without changing your train of thought altogether.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background-color: #edc3c3;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container div {
  width: auto;
}

.container-label {
  background-color: #e1edc3;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-label h1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>A very</div>
    <div>Big chicken</div>
    <div>Comes to</div>
    <div>Dine with us</div>
    <div>Every day</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-label">
    <h1>my label</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```